# How can I fill the part above the line given in Epilog with light gray?

Tags: plotting, functions, filling

How can I fill the part above the line given in Epilog with light gray or something?

```
Plot[{2 Sin[x], 3 x - 2, x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.008]], 
   Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {10, 10}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Show[
 ListLinePlot[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {10, 10}},
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.008]],
  Filling -> Top,
  FillingStyle -> Lighter[Gray, 0.85]],
 Plot[{2 Sin[x], 3 x - 2, x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, GridLines -> Automatic],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To obscure the lines by the `Filling`(adjust the `Opacity` to taste)

```
Show[
 Plot[{2 Sin[x], 3 x - 2, x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, GridLines -> Automatic],
 ListLinePlot[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {10, 10}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.008]], Filling -> Top, 
  FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.75, LightGray]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Would it be OK to make those lines in the filling more blur?

Comment: I noticed that you changed the order of these functions in `Show`. Does that matter?

Comment: So reverse the order and compare the results. Does it make a difference?

Comment: I did but couldn't explain why

Comment: So then you presumably already saw that it **mattered**. As to **why**, `Show` overlays the graphics: the first is the background and the second is the foreground. If the foreground is opaque you cannot see the corresponding background

Comment: Yes, I should have phrased the question better.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a polygon using the coordinates of the epilog line:

```
Plot[{2 Sin[x], 3 x - 2, x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.008]], 
   Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {10, 10}}], 
   LightGray, Opacity[.5], 
   Polygon[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {10, 10}, 
      Scaled[{0, 1}, {10, 10}], 
      Scaled[{0, 1}, {0, 1}]}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`FilledCurve` work for `Line`.

```
line = Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {10, 10}, {0, 10}}];
Plot[{2 Sin[x], 3 x - 2, x^2}, {x, 0, 3}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 Epilog -> {{Gray, Opacity[.5], FilledCurve[line]}, 
   Directive[Red, Dashed, Thickness[0.008]], 
   Line[{{0, 1}, {1, 1}, {10, 10}}]}]
```

[image]